# Format date within an echo

Tags: php, html, css, date, format

I'm trying to format a MySQL formatted date (YYYY-MM-DD) and wish to display the month and year, "September 2012" for example.

My code:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["date"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['date']));` - you can thank the black-magic that is [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) to format your date how you'd like:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row["date"]);
echo htmlspecialchars($date->format('F Y'), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

So with a date like this:

```
$row['date'] = '2012-09-25';
```

This [will print](http://viper-7.com/qhrcA5):

```
September 2012
```

Comment: Is createFromFormat required?

    $date = new DateTime( $row['date'] );

    echo $date->format( "F Y" );

^ Can this replace it?

Comment: @David - Using the constructor with the time string is perfectly acceptable if the date string is [on the list of supported date/time formats](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score 5):

Either select it in that format directly from SQL, e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y') AS formatted_date
```

or do it in php (somewhat less efficient):

```
$formatted = date('F Y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using DateTime like @nickb has suggested?

Comment: nope. DateTime's good for newer forward-looking code, and is much easier to deal with for various "math" type operations on dates. But for simple reformatting like this, especially where the input format is clean/well-defined, date/strtotime is just easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('F Y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: you should add some explanation to your answer

Comment: sorry, my bad. next time will be better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Datetime:

```
$date = date_create($row["date"]);
echo date_format($date, 'F Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use SQL function `DATE_FORMAT (date, format)`

see this link
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it as a new variable to be used multiple times:

```
$datetime = strtotime($row['date']);
$mysqldate = date("M d ", $datetime);
echo $mysqldate;
```