# Printing formatted DATE in PHP through ECHO statement

Tags: php, format

Trying to print the date in "Friday, 15 November 2019" format using the following PHP code using the standard ECHO statement:

```
$mydate='2019-11-15';

echo "Raw mydate printed through echo is $mydate<br>";
echo "Formatted mydate through echo is ". date('l, d F Y', strtotime('$mydate'));
```

However, the output (produced as follows) is strangely taking the formatted date to the first date in UNIX (i.e. nullifying the $mydate variable value). Output is as follows:

```
Raw mydate printed through echo is 2019-11-15
Formatted mydate through echo is Wednesday, 31 December 1969
```

Does PHP ECHO statement does not recognize formatting statements?
If it does, then what am I doing wrong in the above code?

PS:
I have already tried using "`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["date"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>`" as mentioned in [Format date within an echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495547/format-date-within-an-echo), but that does not help either. 
Also used the "`date_create`" statement (like `$mydate = date_create($mydate);`) both before and after the formatting statement, but in all cases the formatted date is going to 31Dec1969. What am I doing wrong here, or does ECHO not support formatting at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$mydate='2019-11-15';

echo "Raw mydate printed through echo is $mydate<br>";
echo "Formatted mydate through echo is ". date('l, d F Y', strtotime($mydate));
```

Your mistake was the single quotes in `strtotime`. If you pass a variable in single quotes it is taken literally. So it actually tries to parse `$mydate` as a literal string, it does not take the value itself. If you want to pass the variable in a string, you should use double quotes `"`.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following change, you are passing `$mydate` as string to the date function.

Remove single quote as shown below:

```
$mydate='2019-11-15';

echo "Raw mydate printed through echo is $mydate<br>";
echo "Formatted mydate through echo is ". date('l, d F Y', strtotime($mydate));
```